# UseEncyption does not play nicely with AWS sns/sqs, messages unable to be delivered to SQS

Tags: masstransit

I have got the following sample project
https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/issue-localstack-masstransit

It uses the latest `MassTransit.AmazonSQS 7.2.2` with `localstack 0.11.2` running SNS/SQS as a docker container.

I have a sample console application that publishes 2 messages, and the consumer receives them and displays on console.

All is good with that.

Now I want to add encryption to all the messages so I add the following

```
var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
aes.GenerateKey();
var key = aes.Key;
```

to the bus factory using the `IAmazonSqsBusFactoryConfigurator` for both publisher and consumer (both the same key, of course).
**After doing so, my receivers don't get any message.** No errors.

[This is the working code](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/issue-localstack-masstransit/-/tree/5ca4c83a4c449ed91f5f32e403bf40ffcf791f4b)
[This is the reproducible issue](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/issue-localstack-masstransit/-/tree/80cc9994d05b6726ea6bbf02f2a3cffb11889dbb) after introducing the `c.UseEncryption(key);`

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Run localstack with sns/sqs

   ```
   docker run -it -e SERVICES=sns,sqs -e TEST_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="000000000000" -e DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1" -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME="localhost" -e -rm --privileged --name localstack_main -p 4566:4566 -p 4571:4571 -p 8080-8081:8080-8081  -v "/tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack" -v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" -e DOCKER_HOST="unix:///var/run/docker.sock" -e HOST_TMP_FOLDER="/tmp/localstack" "localstack/localstack:0.11.2"
   ```
2. Clone repository
3. Run application

   ```
   cd sample/Issue.Localstack.EventBus.MassTransit.SnsSqs.Sample/
   dotnet run
   ```

   You will see

   ```
   Sample started..
   Listening to events..
   Publishing events..
   Press enter to exit
   ```

   but if you comment out the `c.UseEncryption(key);` in both `ConsumerEndpointFactory.cs` and `PublishEndpointFactory.cs` and re-run the console app you'll see that the 2 published events are properly received.

   ```
   Sample started..
   Listening to events..
   Publishing events..
   Press enter to exit
   Received Bar: Bar, Message=this is a bar message
   Received Foo: Foo, Message=this is a foo message
   ```

**Is there a problem with this AmazonSQS implementation?** Or is some incompatibility with something in localstack?

---

Some samples also found in the public repo

```
public static PublisherBusControl Create(SnsSqsPublisherOptions snsSqsPublisherOptions, byte[] key)
{
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAmazonSqs(c =>
    {
        //c.UseEncryption(key);
        
        var hostAddress = snsSqsPublisherOptions.HostAddress;
        var hostConfigurator = new AmazonSqsHostConfigurator(hostAddress);
        hostConfigurator.AccessKey(snsSqsPublisherOptions.AccessKey);
        hostConfigurator.SecretKey(snsSqsPublisherOptions.SecretKey);
        if (snsSqsPublisherOptions.HostConfiguration != null)
        {
            var hostConfiguration = snsSqsPublisherOptions.HostConfiguration;
            hostConfigurator.Config(new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig {ServiceURL = hostConfiguration.SnsServiceUrl});
            hostConfigurator.Config(new AmazonSQSConfig {ServiceURL = hostConfiguration.SqsServiceUrl});
        }
        
        c.Host(hostConfigurator.Settings);
    });
    
    var publisherBusControl = new PublisherBusControl(busControl);
    return publisherBusControl;
}

public static ConsumerBusControl Create(SnsSqsConsumerOptions snsSqsConsumerOptions, Action<IAmazonSqsReceiveEndpointConfigurator> endpointConfigurator, byte[] key)
{
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAmazonSqs(c =>
    {
        //c.UseEncryption(key);
        
        var hostAddress = snsSqsConsumerOptions.HostAddress;
        var hostConfigurator = new AmazonSqsHostConfigurator(hostAddress);
        hostConfigurator.AccessKey(snsSqsConsumerOptions.AccessKey);
        hostConfigurator.SecretKey(snsSqsConsumerOptions.SecretKey);
        if (snsSqsConsumerOptions.HostConfiguration != null)
        {
            var hostConfiguration = snsSqsConsumerOptions.HostConfiguration;
            hostConfigurator.Config(new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig {ServiceURL = hostConfiguration.SnsServiceUrl});
            hostConfigurator.Config(new AmazonSQSConfig {ServiceURL = hostConfiguration.SqsServiceUrl});
        }
        c.Host(hostConfigurator.Settings);
        
        c.ReceiveEndpoint(snsSqsConsumerOptions.QueueName, endpointConfigurator);
    });

    var consumerBusControl = new ConsumerBusControl(busControl);
    return consumerBusControl;
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2021/09/07**
I've been investigating further. With localstack sometimes it gets delivered, sometimes it doesn't. But more importantly, with AWS SNS/SQS, I can see the messages are not delivered from SNS to SQS. I enabled cloudwatch on a SNS topic and I can see the following kind of errors

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageMD5Sum": "b9b92f5125c1b95bc3981e89a3e0b56c",
        "messageId": "e2f3a853-2818-58e3-ae32-f1e26bd01855",
        "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:754027052283:Sample_EventBus_MassTransit_SnsSqs_Common-IBar",
        "timestamp": "2021-09-07 10:40:08.658"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "deliveryId": "88e71359-b405-5795-9fca-4ae8f7cda555",
        "destination": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:754027052283:sample-di-queue",
        "providerResponse": "{\"ErrorCode\":\"InvalidMessageContents\",\"ErrorMessage\":\"Invalid binary character '#x18' was found in the message body, the set of allowed characters is #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF].\",\"sqsRequestId\":\"Unrecoverable\"}",
        "dwellTimeMs": 29,
        "attempts": 1,
        "statusCode": 400
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

Sometimes the error is different

```
"{\"ErrorCode\":\"InvalidMessageContents\",\"ErrorMessage\":\"Invalid binary character '#x1' was found in the message body, the set of allowed characters is #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF].\",\"sqsRequestId\":\"Unrecoverable\"}",
```

I have tried with different keys.

```
var key = Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[]{ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F });
```

and

```
var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
aes.GenerateKey();
var key = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
```

and then converting back from base64 string like

```
var encryptionKey = sqsConfig.UseEncryption(key);
sqsConfig.UseEncryption(key);
```

No luck. The payload is not supported.

Comment: Look at the debug logs, you should see something. Otherwise, it's just code.

Comment: Couldn't see anything at debug logs. It seems to be internal between SNS topic and the SQS where the message cannot be delivered due to invalid binary characters, as explained in my update.

Comment: Well, there you go, the binary encrypted content isn't handled by SNS.